# Avoiding logging in to my ISP on my PC in order to connect to Wi-Fi on my phone

Tags: wireless-networking, router

My ISP requires a username and password to connect with the internet. If I want to connect with Wi-Fi on my mobile, I have to log in to the PC to give the user ID and password.

How can I avoid having to log in to connect to Wi-Fi on my phone?

Comment: What operating system are you using (Windows 7, Windows Vista, Mac OS X...)?

Comment: I am using windows 7 OS

Answer (score 0):

1.) Enable ICS on your Win7 machine through you WiFi device [link here](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot)

or

2.) Get a router that allows you to setup login, then setup NAT/et. al on it

Answer (score 0):

Most routers can handle the login all by themselves.
And that is really the most logical thing to do.

This sort of practice was common 15 years ago, but the world has moved on. 
Having multiple devices in-house is normal now.

As far as the ISP is concerned the router is the customer.
And they should not care what is connecting on the other side of the router.
Having to "enable" the connection from the PC is completely unnecessary.

So check the configuration interface of your router (the part labeled WAN setup, Internet setup or Upstream setup, whatever the manufacturer calls it) and see if you can add the userid/password to that configuration.
If the router doesn't provide the option you will have to buy a better one.

If the router is owned by the ISP without giving you access to it, you better call their helpdesk.
If they can't (or won't) fix it for you get another ISP.
(Or threaten to change ISP, sometimes that helps...)